# Two equal strings representing whitespaces not equals in JS

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, locale

I am encountering a problem trying to replace whitespaces in a number.
For instance, this works, i.e. it returns 27721 as expected:

```js
alert("27 721".replace(/ /g, ""));
```

While - I don't know why - this does not (my browser is in french so thousand separator is a whitespace) :

```js
function getThousandSeparator() {
  var testN = 1000;
  return testN.toLocaleString().replace(/\d/g,"");
}
alert("27 721".replace(new RegExp(getThousandSeparator(), "g"), ""));
```

And if I make the function directly return " " then it works.
Also, if you test :

```
console.log(getThousandSeparator() == " ");
```

it shows false...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(testN.toLocaleString());`?

Comment: Sorry, I have retyped it, here is a copy/paste : 1 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, the separator character is actually an `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space), not a real space.

Comment: You are right and my test was not conclusive because I typed "27 721" whereas `var n = 27721;
alert(n.toLocaleString().replace(new RegExp(getThousandSeparator(), "g"), ""));` effectively works. Thank you !